# How is it possible to change datagrid cell background color when is selected and focused?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to change the `Background` property for the currently selected cell when I double clicked it, but since I'm new to WPF I got some issues. I have tried this way with XAML:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
   <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF333333"/>
         </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

And programmatically:

```
private void DataMapping_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   var row = sender as DataGridRow;
   row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(51, 51, 51));
}
```

[image: Cell Style When Double Clicked]

Any suggestions? [Full code for the Datagrid here.](https://pastebin.com/k8nbwKNf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create and set an `EditingElementStyle` for your data grid column, because you are in *edit-mode* when you double click a cell. In that mode, the data grid cell contains specific controls for editing, like a `TextBox` for text columns, so changing the cell background will not have an effect.

The editing style below sets the `Background` and `Foreground` of the `TextBox` in edit-mode.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridRows}" ...>
   <DataGrid.Resources>
      <!-- ...other data grid resources. -->
      <Style x:Key="DataGridTextColumnEditingStyle" 
             TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
             BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF333333"/>
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
      </Style>
   </DataGrid.Resources>
   <!-- ...other data grid code. -->
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <!-- ...other data grid columns -->
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="CSV Column"
                          IsReadOnly="False"
                          Binding="{Binding Path=CSVColumnValue}"
                          Width="*"
                          Foreground="White"
                          EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridTextColumnEditingStyle}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```